# Getting an error while using the npm link command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-link

I am trying to use the npm link command on my windows computer but getting this error can someone help me in this regard I am stuck on it for a while now

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path C:\projects\app
npm ERR! dest C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\lists
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\projects\app' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\lists'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\projects\app' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\lists']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\projects\app' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\lists'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\projects\app',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\lists' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-27T06_37_20_042Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you please post the command you are running? Have you run it with administrator privileges?

Comment: can you tell me how to run it with administrator privileges as I am relatively new in this

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi npm link is the command I am running

Comment: As your log suggests you are running Windows, if it's windows 8.1 or above, you can use this link:
https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-run-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-win-10.html
summary: press Windows Key+X and select Command prompt with Admin privileges

Comment: @MasoudTahmasebi thanks for the help it worked. Thanks Again!

Comment: So I will add the full answer and you can check that as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **npm link** command must be run with administrator privileges.

if you are running windows you can follow this link: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-run-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-win-10.html

for Unix-based platforms, you can add **sudo** to the first of the command.

Comment: Is this a new requirement? Because I didn't get this error at all until I updated `node` to version 15. 